# How to cache a JSON response?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a JSON file that is used to show prices. The JSON file only refreshes every 30 min server side, but when the client refreshes, he just gets the same version. Is there a way just to have the JSON file to have an expiration date, then re download it, instead of having to keep on download it?

Comment: You could store it in sessionStorage or localStorage. You would need to put a little expiration logic around it though. Maybe store two keys, one controlling the expiration.

Comment: Would there be a way to do it PHP wise? Or should I switch everything over to jQuery?

Comment: You need to research cache controls of your HTTP server and in PHP.

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I am not a PHP guy sorry.

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes "Would there be a way to do it PHP wise? Or should I switch everything over to jQuery?" This demonstrates a complete lack of understanding of JavaScript.

Comment: @naomik Well even on stackoverflow I'm getting roasted. Thanks for your great input!

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes it's not meant to be an insult. The inclination to "switch everything over to jQuery" is just a terrible one. It means you have a lot to learn about PHP, HTTP, JavaScript, and AJAX in general. If anything, to understand the boundaries between them and what each is designed/responsible for.

Comment: @naomik so how would you solve my question? If you're trying to roast me while I'm getting answers for a school project that's kinda just :/

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes if this is for a school project, I'm even less inclined to just tell you the answer. The "I got my degree from StackOverflow" meme is all too sad. JAAulde suggested a good path for you to follow.

Comment: relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @naomik this isn't for a degree, it's for high school.

Answer (score 1):

You could set your server up to return a 304 - Not Modified response if the file has not changed since the date that the browser has stored in its cache for that file. Basically, when a client requests a document, it can send a "If-Modified-Since" date in the request header. If the file has not changed since that date, the server will respond with a 304 - Not Modified response and the client will use the cached version instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your php file that you are calling via ajax:

```
header("Cache-Control: max-age=1800");
header("Cache-Control: public", false);
```

this will let the browser to cache the file for 1800 seconds.

if you are using jQuery, don't forget to turn on the cache property:

```
$.ajax({url:"yourfile.php",cache:true})
```